# How would I Get last max record ID,Increment ID and then add record to table C# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

The following code enters a new record into a table. However, for some reason it is picking up 3126 and a record for that ID already exists. Every time I run this function it increments by 1 but there is already a corresponding value for the id until 3198. How would I change and what changes would I make, so that it gets the max value that already exists in the record and increments the ID by 1 and then add the record.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
try
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCMD = new SqlCommand("InsertNewDeal", conn);

    sqlCMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@Title", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@Office", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 3);
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@EntryBy", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@CSR1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlCMD.Parameters["@id"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;


    sqlCMD.Parameters["@Title"].Value = txtName.Text;
    sqlCMD.Parameters["@Office"].Value = cmbOffice.SelectedValue;
    sqlCMD.Parameters["@CSR1"].Value = cmbCSR.SelectedValue;
    sqlCMD.Parameters["@EntryBy"].Value = LisaDatabaseManager.CurrentCSR.Username;

    CSR user = CSR.LoadCurrentUser();
    sqlCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.newProductionID = (int)sqlCMD.Parameters["@id"].Value;


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Productions SET CountryCode = 'CAN', ProvinceCode = '" + user.GetProvinceCode() + "' WHERE ID = " + newProductionID, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    AddOptionalFields(newProductionID);

    LisaDatabaseManager.DealsTable.Fill(LisaDatabaseManager.DSGlobal.LoadDeals);
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionHandler.LogException("New deal", ex, LogSource.CHECK);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
}
}
```

The stored Procedure to InsertNewdeal is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewDeal]
    @Title varchar(100),
    @EntryBy varchar(50),
    @Office char(3),
    @CSR1 varchar(50),
    @id int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @CamProb int;
    IF @PSOffice = 'VAN'
        set @CamProb = 1;
    else
        set @CamProb = NULL;

    INSERT INTO Productions(Title, EntryDate, EntryBy, Camera, Light, Grip, Generator, Expendables,IsDead, Office, CSR1, Indie,ProbCam)
        VALUES (@Title, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EntryBy, 0,0,0,0,0,0, @Office, @CSR1,0,@CamProb);

    SELECT @id = Scope_Identity();

    INSERT INTO PostMortems(ProductionID,Indie) VALUES (@id,0);

    INSERT INTO Deals(Production, Date, SubRentals,InsuranceOnFile,DealOnFile, ChargeDVan, Charge5Tonne, ChargeDVan_out, Charge5Tonne_out, ChargeBulbReplacement) VALUES(@id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Cost+10%',0,0, 75.00, 100.00, 150.00, 200.00, 1);

    DECLARE ItemCursor Cursor FOR
        select item from dealitems where id in (46048, 46052, 46036, 1, 46054, 15, 46056, 46057, 46058)
        order by
        case
            when id = 46048 then 1
            when id = 46052 then 2
            when id = 46036 then 3
            when id = 1 then 4
            when id = 46054 then 5
            when id = 15 then 6
            when id = 46056 then 7
            when id = 46057 then 8
            else 9
        end

    DECLARE @Description varchar(100)
    DECLARE @count int
    Set @count = 0

    OPEN ItemCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM ItemCursor INTO @Description

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DealMemoItems(Deal, Item, Ord)
        VALUES(@id, @Description, @count)

        SET @count = (@count + 1)

        FETCH NEXT FROM ItemCursor INTO @Description
    END
    CLOSE ItemCursor
    DEALLOCATE ItemCursor
END
```

Comment: Can you check what the sp InsertNewDeal is doing which returns the id value. The problem may be with the stored proc rather than the .net code.

Comment: Also you should use Using (SqlConnection conn = new ...) {}

Comment: Is the property Identity for the ID column set to Yes? If yes what is the current value for it `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table')`?

Comment: Well, looking at the SP the ID should be correct, but given the fact that is not then I bet that someone has manually added records to your productions table disabling the IDENTITY mechanism (`SET IDENTITY_INSERT productions ON, add record, SET IDENTITY_INSERT produtions OFF`) but forgetting to call `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Productions', RESEED, ......the_new_max_ident_value)`

Comment: Can you check which table you are having a problem while inserting? There are two tables - Productions and Deals. You get the id value from the first and insert it into the latter. Is it the case that the id is already present in Deals table? In that case, have you a FK constraint on Deals referring to Productions. In case a higher id is needed from Productions table, you can use a dbcc reseed to increment the value to a high number.

Comment: Can you please explain this further @Steve....I am a bit of a beginner at this.

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean siddharth...I'm not quite sure I understand dbcc reseed....? But yes there are FK Contraints on a number of tables refereeing to Productions.

Comment: @Masa Rumi - As mentioned by Steve above, you can use a DBCC CHECKIDENT RESEED command to increment the current seed value of your Identity column to a higher value of your choice (check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057(v=sql.90).aspx). Also, I wanted to know if the id value (taken from Productions table) after the insert is a lower number then expected ? In that case you may need to reseed the Productions table.

Comment: Thanks. It is a lower number than expected. It should be at 3198 but it is at 3125.

Comment: And that's the problem. Call DBCC CHECKIDENT('productions', RESEED, 3198) or 3197 if you want the next ID equals to 3198.....

Comment: `DBCC CHECKIDENT ("Productions", RESEED, 3197);` The new id from a new insert should give you 3198 then.

Comment: GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Productions)
GO

Would I have to do the same for the foreign Constraints as well. Make sure their ID is the same???

Comment: Your FK constraints should not be a problem as all the ID values used in tables other than Productions table will already be existing in Productions. And any new ID values generated after an insert into Productions will be used in the other tables.

Comment: Checking identity information: current identity value '3263092', current column value '3265141'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

this is the result.... However the the last ID of the Record in the Productions table is 3265141. ...Any chance how that would even happen. It was all okay before I migrated the databases.

Comment: I cannot reseed the value to 3265141. The following are the commands and the results:

GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Productions, RESEED, 3265141)
GO

Checking identity information: current identity value '3265141', current column value '3265141'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM <yourtable> ORDER BY id DESC) + 1
```

This gets the last highest ID from the table, and increments it by one. You can put it right into your SQL insert statement, as a value, like below:

```
INSERT INTO <YOURTABLE> (id, name)
values (
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM <yourtable> ORDER BY id DESC) + 1,
     'Goober fish'
);
```

Comment: and hope that none inserts another record at the same time

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you would absolutely have to hope that. It's definitely not best practice. But it answers his question of making his query "...so that it gets the max value that already exists in the record and increments the ID by 1."

Comment: I think that its problem is more complex. He has an Identity on that column, so no need to calculate manually

Comment: Sometimes when someone asks you to use a old shoe or a glass bottle to drive in a nail, [they need to be told to go get a hammer](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) (this is also known as the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Steve is talking about solving `Y` and you are trying to help him solve `X`).

Comment: Additionally, this application is replicated across locations. Replication is working. The application and insertion is working on other locations minus this. The ID increment seems to be off only on this location.... Not sure if this helps in anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Could you not change your stored procedure to use:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Which would return the id of the last inserted record. You cannot rely on the id being equal to the largest id incremented by one, as ids can be reused overtime.

Note this is a SQL Server solution, but there are usually equivalents in other database engines.

Comment: I agree that is a better solution, as it returns the id for the connection.

Comment: My stored procedure is already using that. Will add the stored procedure in an edit above.